# Where do I place a image on a JavaFX project from eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, image, javafx

I'm trying to put a image from disk in my project, but I don't know from where to load it.

```
primaryStage.setTitle("Load Image");
StackPane sp = new StackPane(); //**stack pane**
Image img = new Image("mario.png"); // **here is my issue**
```

What place do I put in the img path?

```
ImageView imgView = new ImageView(img);
sp.getChildren().add(imgView);

// Adding HBox to the scene
Scene scene = new Scene(sp, 400, 400);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a "resources" package and copy your images and other files this package and for reading an image you can use following line:

```
Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("/resources/image.jpg").toURI().toString());
ImageView iv = new ImageView(img);
```

Comment: this resources package is created  in bin folder?

Comment: Yes it is located in bin directory. Hopes it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the image works like so :

> /bin/br/com/casa/bluekepper

works, like:

```
Image img = new Image("/br/com/casa/bluekepper/img.gif");
```